# A Theory Book about sequence diagram that look like my diagram

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram, sequence-diagram

I've already submit my sequence diagram task, and i just realized that my sequence diagram is wrong(not same with the theory that i already submitted), and i need to find a source book about sequence diagram that look exactly same with my sequence diagram (no colon and underline). Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: no colon and no underline means no correct sequence diagram according to UML. In SysML there are some examples in the standard that also miss both. But only for some very special cases. Btw. welcome to HomerworkOverflow

Answer (score 0):

No, sequence charts illustrate interactions between instances, which are identified in the UML using an underline and a colon between *name* and *type* of instance. This is not a theory, it's a standard.